# CCProgressTimer in cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Perhaps this question have been repeated many time, but I couldn't found helpful material. Also this is my first project in cocos2D, i want to implement the ProgressBar, CCProgressTimer in cocos2D. I have two sprites, first is moving and the second one is the player (to which you can move), If user successfully eat the first moving object then the progress should be incremented else if it misses then the progress will be decremented. I need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just make it so when the player wins, you add another sprite to the progress bar. no need to ccprogresstimer. or push to an array, and each time you win, the progressbar checks the array count. that way you can know how many wins you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my code I used for rounded CCProgressTimers (it looks like clock). You possibly need to have a background sprite and a "movable" sprite above background sprite.

```
CCSprite *movableSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"health100.png"];
CCProgressTimer *healthBar = [CCProgressTimer progressWithSprite:movableSprite];
healthBar.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeRadial; // This is for round progress timer. Possible value for horizontal bar will be kCCProgressTimerTypeHorizontalBarLR

healthBar.midpoint = ccp(0,0.5); // Here is where all magic is
healthBar.barChangeRate = ccp(1, 0); // If you need horizontal bar progress play with these parameters.

// Here we will start an animation process. 
// You can do it without animation just setting up healthBar.progress = 45.0f; (45%)
[healthBar runAction:[CCProgressFromTo actionWithDuration:2.0f from:0.0f to:100.0f]];        

healthBar.position = ccp(100, 100); // It's your position

[self addChild:healthBar];
```